# How is mana value calculated for a melded card?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-meld

How is mana value/CMC calculated for melded cards like [Mishra, Lost to Phyrexia](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=588285); [Urza, Planeswalker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=588290); and [Titania, Gaea Incarnate](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=588292) cards?

Both Google and Scryfall calculate the mana values as such, but there is no mana in the top right corner:

- Mishra, Lost to Phyrexia CMC=7
- Urza, Planeswalker CMC=8
- Titania, Gaea Incarnate CMC=3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The mana value (formerly known as "converted mana cost") of a melded permanent is defined as part of Rule 713, Meld Cards:

> 713.4b While the two cards of a meld pair are on the battlefield as a melded permanent, ... its mana value is the sum of the mana values of its front faces.

Therefore the mana value of [Mishra, Lost to Phyrexia](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mishra%2C%20Lost%20to%20Phyrexia) is the sum of mana values of [Mishra, Claimed by Gix](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mishra%2C%20Claimed%20by%20Gix) (4) and [Phyrexian Dragon Engine](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Phyrexian%20Dragon%20Engine) (3).